# How can this population extinct because of gender inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This population has the properties as follows:

(1) It is an isolated population, which means the individuals can only mate with others in this population.

(2) It is a monogamy population, which means each individual should only has one mate.

(3a) Each couple should give birth to N children. N is an integer.

(3b)(alternative to 3a) Each couple gives birth to k children, and k follows a Poisson distribution: P(k)=$\frac{N^k}{k!}e^{-N}$. N can be a non-integer.

(4) The length of breeding cycle in this population is constant and consistent from individual to individual. All the individuals only give birth at their fixed breeding age.

(5) There is a gene called DOOM. If one spouse in a couple carries the DOOM gene, they will give birth to male children at the probability of Pm. A couple without DOOM has the same probability to give birth to male children and female children.

(6) If one spouse in a couple carries the DOOM gene, their children will carry DOOM gene.

(7) All the individuals can not distinguish those with DOOM from those without DOOM.

(8) Initial conditions: The percentage of male DOOM carriers equals to female DOOM carriers, and is $q_0$. The percentage of male DOOM non-carriers equals to female DOOM non-carriers, and is $(1-2q_0)/2$. At the beginning, all the individuals are at their breeding age.

[Question] In what condition given by N, Pm and $q_0$, this population will diminish gradually?

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? I think it is an interesting question, but maybe you can give some characteristic behavior you already discovered.

Comment: I haven't tried yet. I am think of doing some stochastic simulation first. But I guest that it is not quite possible to obtain a close form solution by only simulation.

Comment: Maybe you can get some small results at least and look for a pattern.

Comment: I think in (3) "spouse" should be "couple". Not only is "spouse" not used outside the context of humans (and the verb "mate" rarely used within that context), I don't think that male individuals give birth, and this is a key factor in this problem. So if $N=1$ the population will go extinct regardless. Also the question suggests $N$ is a constant integer, not an average over the population; this make the problem very rigid.

Comment: The problem is that if we use an average N, we have to assume a distribution for N. This will make the solution much more complicated.

Comment: Is the gene always propagated to the next generation even when only one of the pair carry it?

Comment: Are there any conditions on the initial population? Gender equality, percentage of DOOM-carriers, etc? Is the model discrete in time?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to approach the problem this way:

Let $T_0 = m_0 + f_0$ be the initial population. And, in general, let $T_k$ be the population after the breeding cycle $k$; $m_k$ and $f_k$ the population of males and females of the $k$-th generation, respectively. Assuming ($3$a), that individuals have a life expectancy of $d$ breeding cycles, and that there's no breeding between different generations, we have:

$$T_k = N \min(m_{k-1}, f_{k-1}) + \sum_{j=\max(0,k-d)}^{k-1} m_j + f_j$$

Furthermore, if $P_d^k$ is the probability that an individual of the $k$-th generation has the DOOM gene, and $P_m$ is the probability that such an individual has male children, we have:

$m_k = N \left(\frac{1}{2}(1-P_d^k)+P_m P_d^k\right)\min(m_{k-1},f_{k-1})$

$f_k = N \left(\frac{1}{2}(1-P_d^k)+(1-P_m) P_d^k\right)\min(m_{k-1},f_{k-1})$

$P_d^k = P_d^{k-1}\left(2 - P_d^{k-1}\right)$

Note that $\{P_d^k\}_k$ is an increasing sequence. Now, set

$A_k(P_m) = N \left(\frac{1}{2}(1-P_d^k)+P_m P_d^k\right)$

$B_k(P_m) = N \left(\frac{1}{2}(1-P_d^k)+(1-P_m) P_d^k\right)$

From the recursive relations for $m_k$ and $f_k$ we have:

$m_k = A_k \min(A_{k-1}, B_{k-1}) \cdots \min(A_{1}, B_{1}) \min(m_0, f_0)$

$f_k = B_k \min(A_{k-1}, B_{k-1}) \cdots \min(A_{1}, B_{1}) \min(m_0, f_0)$

Now, you just have to study three cases:

- $P_m = \frac{1}{2}$:

In this case, $A_k = B_k$, so $\displaystyle m_k = f_k = 2 \min(m_0, f_0) \left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^k$, and $m_k$, $f_k$ converge iff $N = 0, 1, 2$. In that case, $\displaystyle \lim_k T_k = m_k + f_k = 0, d \min(m_0, f_0), 2d\min(m_0, f_0)$, respectively.

- $P_m > \frac{1}{2}$:
- $P_m < \frac{1}{2}$:

The last can be solved the same way.

Comment: $P_d$ will change with generation, so it also should be updated.

Comment: Well, if we assume that $P_d^k$ is the probability that an individual of the $k$-th generation has the DOOM gene, and that it is transmitted iff both in a couple have it, then $P_d^{k+1}={\left(P_d^k\right)}^2$

Comment: In my question, it has already assumed that DOOM gene will be transmitted to next generation if only one parent has it. Furthermore, $P_d$ is also affected by the percentage of male DOOM carriers and the percentage of female DOOM carriers in each generation. And these percentages will vary among generations.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. Now the DOOM gene is transmitted whenever any individual in a couple has it.

Comment: It seems like you're writing expressions for the expectations of $m_k$ and $f_k$. But these should be RVs not just numbers..

Comment: I don't think life expectancy has to be considered, because the long-term change of the population is independent from life expectancy. Whether a population will extinct is only determined by the change among different generation, so we only have to investigate the number and composition of generations.

Comment: @ChaosMage True, life expectancy is not important when studying asymptotic behaviour, but neither it complicates this model...

Comment: @KaiSikorski As I see it, this is what should be studied to explain the asymptotic behaviour of the population. But sure, there might be a better approach

Comment: Yeah, if you could get an expression for E[m_k] etc that would be sufficient. But I don't believe you can write a recurrence just in terms of the expectations, ie I don't think that you can express the expectation at the kth step just in terms of the expectation at the previous step. What is needed is a master equation.

Comment: @marc Maybe there is some problem of this equation: $P_d^k=P_d^{k-1}(2-P_d^{k-1})$.  I guess, this equation is based on the assumption that the number of males and the number of females are equal. But it is not true for the people with DOOM gene.

Comment: $m_k=N(\frac{1}{2}(1-P_d^k)+P_mP_d^k)min(m_{k-1},f_{k-1})$ is also problematic. 2*min(m_{k-1},f_{k-1}) is the number of people who have spouse. However, the DOOM gene ratio of the people who have spouse is different from that of the people who do not have spouse, so $P_d^k$ can not be applied here in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that basically either the doom gene spreads to the entire population very quickly or it goes extinct. Assuming the population size is large to begin with, and close to evenly split between males/females under the setup you described the doom gene will almost always spread to the whole population, so maybe let's just look at that case.

I will just model the number of breeding age couples of each generation $C_i$. From what I remember stochastic systems like this always go extinct in finite time. The expected value of the population size at time $i$ can still be an increasing function of $i$, so I guess you want to know under what circumstances that is true.

After a breeding event in case 3a we will always end up with $N C_i$ individuals, but the question is how many couples this corresponds to. Let's temporarily introduce the variable representing the number of males at time $i+1$, $M_{i+1}$. This follows the binomial distribution. And we have 
$C_{i+1} = \min(M_{i+1},N C_i - M_{i+1})$.
Let's assume $C_{i} \gg 1$ so we can use the normal approximation and seek an expression for the expectation of the ratio $\frac{C_{i+1}}{C_i}$.
$E[\frac{C_{i+1}}{C_i}] \approx \int_{-\infty}^{C_i N/2} \frac{m}{C_i} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi N C_i P_m (1-P_m)}} e^{-\frac{(m-N C_i P_m)^2}{2N C_i P_m (1-P_m)}}\mathrm{d}m + \int_{C_i N/2}^{\infty} \frac{N C_i  - m}{C_i} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi N C_i P_m (1-P_m)}} e^{-\frac{(m-N C_i P_m)^2}{2N C_i P_m (1-P_m)}}\mathrm{d}m$

I was able to do these in mathematica; and subsequently do a large $C_i$ expansion. Not surprisingly I found that to leading order

$E[C_{i+1}/C_i] = N (1-P_m)$

So in order for the expected size of the population to grow you need the expected number of females born to each couple to be greater than $1$ (I assumed $P_m \ge 1/2$).

EDIT: I realized later that the integral asymptotic will come out very cleanly using the method of Laplace. I don't really want to put more time into this, but if you want a cleaner derivation apply this http://bit.ly/1bYXspG

Comment: It seems that your final expression of $E[C_{i+1}/C_i]$ goes against our intuition. In the model as I described, the gender inequality should show an symmetrical effect on the growth of population, in another word, ($P_m=x$) should have the same effect as ($P_m=1-x$).

Comment: Like I said in my post the assumption $P_m \ge 1/2$ was made in the derivation. It is symmetric the formula would just look more complicated. In particular it would be $N\min((1-P_m),P_m)$. There's no loss in generality by assuming one is larger than the other, so that's what I did.

Comment: In particular if $P_m < 1/2$ just define $P_f = 1-P_m$  and change the subscripts in my derivation from $f$ to $m$...

Comment: How did you derive the approximation of $E[\frac{C_{i+1}}{C_i}]$ ?

Comment: I just used Mathematica, but I think it should come out cleanly using Laplace's method described in the link. Use $C_i$ as the big parameter (think they call it $M$ in the article). You'll find that only one of the integrals has a critical point hence only that one will contribute asymptotically.

Comment: I mean how did you obtain this formula: $E[\frac{C_{i+1}}{C_i}] \approx \int_{-\infty}^{C_i N/2} ...$

Comment: Oh so its basically the expectation of the expression I derived $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\min(m,N C_i -m)}{C_i} f(m)dm$  where f is the normal approximation to the binomial distribution. There's a section on this in the binomial distribution Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a recurrence sequence for this model as follows.

First, we make such definitions:

$N_{d,m}^{(k)}$ is number of male DOOM carriers in the $k$-th generation.

$N_{d,f}^{(k)}$ is number of female DOOM carriers in the $k$-th generation.

$N_{n,m}^{(k)}$ is number of male DOOM non-carriers in the $k$-th generation.

$N_{n,f}^{(k)}$ is number of female DOOM non-carriers in the $k$-th generation.

$T^{(k)}$ is number of couples in the $k$-th generation.

$T_{d,d}^{(k)}$ is number of couples each consisting of 2 DOOM carriers in the $k$-th generation.

$T_{d,n}^{(k)}$ is number of couples each consisting of 1 male DOOM carrier and 1 female DOOM non-carrier in the $k$-th generation.

$T_{n,d}^{(k)}$ is number of couples each consisting of 1 male non-DOOM carrier and 1 female DOOM carrier in the $k$-th generation.

$T_{n,n}^{(k)}$ is number of couples each consisting of 2 DOOM non-carriers in the $k$-th generation.

Then we have:

$T^{(k)}=min((N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}) , (N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)}))$

$T_{d,d}^{(k)}=T^{(k)}\frac{N_{d,m}^{(k)}}{N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}}\frac{N_{d,f}^{(k)}}{N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)}}$

$T_{d,n}^{(k)}=T^{(k)}\frac{N_{d,m}^{(k)}}{N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}}\frac{N_{n,f}^{(k)}}{N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)}}$

$T_{n,d}^{(k)}=T^{(k)}\frac{N_{n,m}^{(k)}}{N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}}\frac{N_{d,f}^{(k)}}{N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)}}$

$T_{n,n}^{(k)}=T^{(k)}\frac{N_{n,m}^{(k)}}{N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}}\frac{N_{n,f}^{(k)}}{N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)}}$

As assumed in the model, a couple with at least 1 DOOM carrier has the probability $P_m$ to give birth to boy.

In the $k$-th generation, the number of couples with at least 1 DOOM carrier is $T_{d,d}^{(k)}+T_{d,n}^{(k)}+T_{n,d}^{(k)}$.

Therefore, we have:

$N_{d,m}^{(k+1)}=P_m (T_{d,d}^{(k)}+T_{d,n}^{(k)}+T_{n,d}^{(k)}) N$

$N_{d,f}^{(k+1)}=(1-P_m) (T_{d,d}^{(k)}+T_{d,n}^{(k)}+T_{n,d}^{(k)}) N$

$N_{n,m}^{(k+1)}=N_{n,f}^{(k+1)}=0.5 T_{n,n}^{(k)} N$

Then we can obtain:

$\frac{(N_{d,m}^{(k+1)}+N_{d,f}^{(k+1)})}{(N_{n,m}^{(k+1)}+N_{n,f}^{(k+1)})}\frac{(N_{n,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)})}{(N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{d,f}^{(k)})}=\frac{N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{n,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)}}{N_{n,m}^{(k)}N_{n,f}^{(k)}}\frac{(N_{n,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)})}{(N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{d,f}^{(k)})}>1$

which means the ratio of DOOM carriers will always increase, indicating that the DOOM carriers will take up the entire population eventually. So we obtain

$\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow\infty}N_{n,m}^{(k)}=0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow\infty}N_{n,f}^{(k)}=0$

Furthermore, we can have:

$\frac{T^{(k+1)}}{T^{(k)}}=\frac{min((N_{d,m}^{(k+1)}+N_{n,m}^{(k+1)}) , (N_{d,f}^{(k+1)}+N_{n,f}^{(k+1)}))}{T^{(k)}}= \frac{min((N_{d,m}^{(k+1)}+N_{n,m}^{(k+1)}) , (N_{d,f}^{(k+1)}+N_{n,f}^{(k+1)}))}{T^{(k)}}=\frac{min((\frac{P_{m}T^{(k)}(N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{n,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)})N}{(N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)})(N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)})}+N_{n,m}^{(k+1)}) , (\frac{(1-P_{m})T^{(k)}(N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{n,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)})N}{(N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)})(N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)})}+N_{n,f}^{(k+1)}))}{T^{(k)}}=min((\frac{P_{m}(N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{n,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)})N}{(N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)})(N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)})}+N_{n,m}^{(k+1)}) , (\frac{(1-P_{m})(N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{n,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)})N}{(N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)})(N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)})}+N_{n,f}^{(k+1)}))$

As $k \rightarrow\infty$, $N_{n,m}^{(k)}$ and $N_{n,f}^{(k)}$ $\rightarrow 0$, we have

$\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{T^{(k+1)}}{T^{(k)}} =\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} min(\frac{P_{m}(N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{n,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)})N}{(N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)})(N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)})},\frac{(1-P_{m})(N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{d,m}^{(k)}N_{n,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)}N_{d,f}^{(k)})N}{(N_{d,m}^{(k)}+N_{n,m}^{(k)})(N_{d,f}^{(k)}+N_{n,f}^{(k)})}) = min(P_{m}N,(1-P_{m})N)$

If N<2, $\frac{T^{(k+1)}}{T^{(k)}}<1$, which means the number of couples will decrease consistently in the long term, as a result, the population will extinct regardless of the value of $P_m$.

When N>=2,

If $(\frac{1}{N}-P_m)(1-\frac{1}{N}-P_m)<0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{T^{(k+1)}}{T^{(k)}}>1$, and the population will increase.

If $(\frac{1}{N}-P_m)(1-\frac{1}{N}-P_m)>0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{T^{(k+1)}}{T^{(k)}}<1$, and the population will extinct.

If $(\frac{1}{N}-P_m)(1-\frac{1}{N}-P_m)=0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{T^{(k+1)}}{T^{(k)}}=1$, and the population will reach a stable size eventually.

The initial conditions ($N_{d,m}^{(1)}$, $N_{d,f}^{(1)}$, $N_{n,m}^{(1)}$, $N_{n,f}^{(1)}$) will not affect the conclusions above if and only if these values are positive.

Comment: Again like the previous post you are writing expressions for the mean number of doom doom carriers for example. In particular $T_{d,d}$, etc. are actually a random variables that have some distribution; not just a deterministic number. In the limit of your population being large, that's a fine approach but you should be aware that it is an approximation of this system.

Comment: If you're going to rely on simulations why not just simulate the full stochastic system though..

Comment: Also, your expressions are equivalent to what I derived, you're just writing them in a non-intuitive way. The first term is (1-"Expected number of males")/N. The second is ("Expected number of females" - 1)/N. Probably better to multiply through by $-N^2$ on both sides so you have $(P_m N -1)((1-P_m)N - 1) > 0$. Assuming $N \ge 2$ and $0 \le P_m \le 1$ both terms can't be negative, so if the product is positive that means both terms are positive individually. Hence both the expected number of males produced per couple and the expected number of females is greater than 1